# Как посчитать формулу для Сочетаний в джаваскрипте?

Tags: javascript, функции

Вот мой код на html:

```
  <p>Введите количество, из скольки сочетания <input type="text" id="bigNum"></p>
    <p>Введите количество, сколько сочетаний <input type="text" id="smallNum"></p>
    <button onclick="build()">найти количество сочетаний</button>
    <p id="out"></p>
    <hr>
    <p id="out2"></p>
```

Вот мой код на js:

```
var j, fac, n, m, facN, facM, facNM, soch, height;
function fac() {
    fac=1;

    for (var i=1;i<=j;i++) {
           fac = fac * i;
    }
      console.log(fac);
}

function build() {
    n = document.getElementById('bigNum').value;
    m = document.getElementById('smallNum').value;
    j=n;
    fac();
    facN=fac;    
    j=m;
    fac();
    facM=fac;
    j=n-m;
    fac();
    facNM=fac;
    soch=facN/facM/facNM;
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += soch+ '<br>' + facN + ' ' +facM +' ' +facNM;
    document.getElementById('out2').innerHTML
}
```

да, много лишних переменных, но не суть.

По идее, первая функция fac() высчитывает факториал числа j, и после работы этой функции переменная fac носит значение факториала числа, которое до вызова этой функции хранилось в переменной j.

В функции, которая должна считать количество сочетаний, берётся два аргумента, сколько элементов во всей выборке, и сколько элементов надо выбрать. Потом три раза обсчитывается факториал, таким образом что перед вызовом функции в переменную j записывается нужный аргумент, вызывается функция, и значение переменной fac уже присваивается нужной переменной.(я знаю, что можно использовать функцию с параметрами, но пока решил без них). А потом уже проводится формула, и должен быть вывод результата.
Но проблема в том, что это не работает, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Ты не можешь вызвать fac(), потому что это переменная. Переименуй функцию.

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек!